# MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException Version string not in acceptable format error while connecting to -log enabled instance

Tags: c#, mysql

When I connect to the MySQL instance I receive the following error

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException
  HResult=0x80004005
  Message=Version string not in acceptable format
  Source=MySql.Data
  StackTrace:
   at MySql.Data.Common.DBVersion.Parse(String versionString)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Open()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.CreateNewPooledConnection()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetPooledConnection()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.TryToGetDriver()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetConnection()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()
   at <Program>$.<<Main>$>d__0.MoveNext() in C:\Users\ADMIN\source\repos\TestInfogram\TestInfogram\Program.cs:line 11

  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    [External Code]
    <Program>$.<Main>$(string[]) in Program.cs
```

My connection string is as below

```
var mscon = new MySqlConnection("server=myserverip;uid=myusername;pwd=mypassword;database=mydatabase;charset=utf8;");
```

I am able to connect to this instance from workbench and the user has all privileges. When I run `SELECT VERSION();`  , it returns

> '5.7.33-log'

MySql server is running on another machine and I have only SQL access to that machine

Comment: What version of MySql.Data? You could try https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/ as an alternative library, to see if it doesn't have this issue.

Comment: MySql.Data version is 8.0.26 .

Yes I was able to make a successful connection using MySqlConnector . Thanks

Comment: I'll add that as an answer; I don't have any better suggestions to get MySql.Data working, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a bug in MySql.Data, albeit one I haven't see reported before. You could report it to Oracle's bug tracker, and hope for a fix in an upcoming release: https://bugs.mysql.com.

In the meantime, as a workaround, you could try switching to an alternative ADO.NET library, [MySqlConnector](https://mysqlconnector.net/), as that should allow you to connect to this server.